# MOSFETs current regulators 1 input

Tags: current, current-limiting, linear-regulator

Can we use a MOSFET to act like a single inout current regulator? Here is my idea.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWifTk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the voltage on the input is greater than the threshold voltage of the MOSFET electrons start flowing from the ground to the 3.3V outlet .

Rb is much much bigger than the ohmic resistance of the MOSFET( width of conducting channel) so any variations won't practically change current.

I am having trouble in making a circuit using only 1 DC voltage source. How to do it?

Comment: This circuit lacks a feedback op-amp to sense current, thus converting volts to amps in a predictable way.

Comment: Ok but the current stays approximarely the same correct?

Comment: With a servo-amp, a fixed voltage locks the current.

Comment: @HelenaWells It will only stay the same if 3.3V and Rb stays the same, in which case you might as well just add a second resistor in series and size that to limit the current through everything. Also, if \$R_b >> R_{M1}\$ then modulating M1 won't really change the current since Rb will dominate. You have it backwards. A current source is approximated when you take a voltage source in series with a very high resistance and connect them to a load whose resistance may change but is always much less than the first resistor.

Comment: I dont know what current source is.I know that voltage on a closed loop creates current and I know Ohms law , KCL and KVL. I do not know mesh or node analysis.And this is circuit is about giving any input voltage but get steady current as output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it may not be a good idea.

If you look at the output characteristic curves of a MOSFET:
[image]

You can see that the FET is a good current source say from 1V to 50V with Vgs=4.5V.  The drain current varies only very slightly. (If you want to operate with a 3.3V supply only, you'll need a low Vth FET.)

However, the threshold of the FET will shift dramatically with temperature, so you won't get the SAME constant current as the temperature of your device changes.

Also, because the threshold varies considerably from part to part, if you build more than one of these you will also have a different load current.

The current will also be non-linear with respect to the applied gate voltage.

If any of that matters to you, you're much better off using an op-amp and negative feedback to create a current sink for accurate, repeatable current, as in this application circuit from ADI/LT:

[image]

Comment: Note that a precision 1 K resistor changes it to 1mA / volt. Sometimes I make C = 100 nF to stop ringing on changes in load. V++ for the MOSFET can be much higher than Vcc for the op-amp. As it is in linear mode, MOSFET may need a heat-sink.

Comment: Ok John but how am I going to draw the circuit with 1 single battery?

Comment: And from the diagram you posted ( if i read it correctly ) it seems that current depends a lot on gate to substrate voltage because I see for a change of 2V of VGS a change of 2A Id.Are you sure you didnt mean mA?

Comment: @HelenaWells No, the diagram is correct, it's from the datasheet for the IRF530.  I'm not understanding the challenge to draw the circuit with 1 battery?  What's the battery voltage?  Are you concerned about the reference voltage to the gate or the op-amp?  If the battery voltage is sufficient for the circuits to run, hook the + terminal to the V+ nodes and the - terminal to ground.  Maybe use a voltage reference part if you need a stable voltage reference to set the current, or a pot to adjust it.